# A combinatorial proof of $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, alternative-proof

The property $\forall n\in\mathbb N,\,\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ was given in our first chapter on probability theory among binomial coefficients' properties. It is really easy to prove with the formula $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, yet it is mentioned in other course notes, so I thought it has other combinatorial meanings and that it may even be quite special (like the fact that the property doesn't hold only for positive integers but for [all real numbers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Coefficient_with_Two)). So could you please tell me if that's is the case? I'll also be grateful if you shared your combinatorial interpretations of it. Personally, the one above is mine. I'm not accurate at combinatorics so please verify if it is correct.

The case $n=1$ is trivial since $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=0$ and, combinatorially, we know that $\binom{n}{k}=0$ when $n<k$ because we can't take a number of elements which is higher than the one of available elements.

So suppose that $n\ge 2$. Notice that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}i=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. This remark is the idea behind the proof.

Suppose we have an urn that contains $n$ red balls numbered $1,2,\dots,n$. There are two ways to count the number of ways of drawing $2$ balls without taking order in consideration:

- We know that this number of ways is given by $\binom{n}{2}$.
- (This second way of counting is what makes me doubt about the veracity of the proof) Let us fix $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. By the fundamental principle of counting, the number of combinations that contains balls one with the number $i$ and the other one with no number less than $i$ is $n-i$ (this fits with the case $i=n$ because in this case no such a combination is possible since all balls' numbers are less than or equal $n$). On the other hand, it is easy to show that any combination of two balls among $n$ can be counted only once like this (Take $i$ the minimum of the two numbers given by the ball. We can't take the maximum because the other number given by the balls is smaller and it's for this reason that the condition "no number less than $i$" exists). Therefore the number of ways is:$\sum_{i=1}^nn-i=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}n-i=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

As a conclusion: $\forall n\in\mathbb N,\,\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Comment: I think this is more or less correct. There is also a geometric-combinatoric way to do it by noticing that $\binom{n}{2}$ is the number of line segments between any two vertices of a polygon. I think it is a cleaner interpretation since it's easy to understand with a picture. Fundamentally the approaches are the same though.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes that's better, and the fact that $\binom{n}{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}n-i$ becomes really easy to see. Thank you very much!

Comment: @CameronWilliams By the way, after reading the other answers which are really good I prefer yours. So could you post it as an answer? It'll be the one I'll accept since it's the one I like the most now.

Comment: Sure thing. $\,\,$

Comment: 1 year later, I get a downvote... Would the downvoter explain why?

Comment: Ugh I'm not sure. It's a *really* bad behavior by some users. I have always felt like downvotes on this site should come with further action, particularly a (permanent) comment.

Comment: Ah Hi there :) Yeah you're **totally** right! It might be considered quite bad if the post is of an obviously bad quality, which doesn't seem to be the case for my question (except the "above in the last line of first paragraph which should be bellow; maybe he things someone who can't distinguish both have no place here hhh ;) ). If only, as you said, he explained what he didn't like with a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer by request.

There is a nice geometric-combinatoric way to do this via polygons. Consider an $n$-gon, then the number of line segments between any two vertices is (by definition) $\binom{n}{2}$. If you number the vertices $1$ through $n$, then vertex $1$ connects with $n-1$ vertices, vertex $2$ connects with $n-2$ vertices (since it's already connected to vertex $1$), etc. Adding all of these up, you get

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (n-i) = n^2 - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 8):

To make a subset of $\{1,...,n\}$ of 2 elements, you have $n$ choice for the first element, $n-1$ choice for the seconde, and since the order is not important, you divide by $2$ (since $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ is the same). Therefore you get $$\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, but this way isn't different from the one that gives the formula $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. In a way, it's taking the case $k=2$, but on the other hand it is true that for $k=2$ it is easier to see.

Answer (score 6):

What you have works.

Alternatively, if you draw two balls with replacement, there are $n^2$ possible outcomes. In $n$ of these you’ve drawn the same ball twice, so there are $n^2-n=n(n-1)$ possible outcomes in which you get two different balls. Each pair of balls can occur in either of two orders, so $n(n-1)$ counts each *unordered* pair of balls twice. Thus, there are therefore $\frac{n(n-1)}2$ different unordered pairs of balls, and $\binom{n}2=\frac{n(n-1)}2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Basically, it's in almost that way that the formula $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, but your method is different in a way that makes the case $k=2$ really special. I like it.

Comment: @Scientifica: You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot think of a really nice way, the issue is the division by $2$.   But doing the closely related $2\binom{n}{2}=n(n-1)$ is easy.

There are $n$ teams in a league, and each team plays every other team twice, at home and away. So the number of games is $2\binom{n}{2}$. But every game is a home game for somebody, and every one of the $n$ teams plays $n-1$ home games, for a total of $n(n-1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's a nice way to interpret  unordered pairs of $n$ objects.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

There are $\binom n2$ ways of selecting two integers $i$ and $j$ such that $1\le i<j\le n$, almost by definition. That means:

\begin{align}
\binom n2&=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}1\\
&=\sum_{1\le j\le n\text{ and }1\le i<j}1\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}1\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n(j-1)\\
&\qquad(j':=j-1)\\
&=\sum_{j'=0}^{n-1}j'\\
&=\frac{n(n-1)}2
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your method is in a certain way the same as mine but written in a much better way and the calculation you made is powerfully beautiful!

Comment: By the way there's little typo: in the first line it should be, as you know, $1\le i<j\le n$.

Comment: @Scientifica Yes, thank you. Edited.